# laravel update shouldn't do anything if no value changed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

If I open a form to edit and without changing any value just hit Submit button to update, it updates the row in the table i.e. it changes the updated_at time and even executes some code in `bootXXXX(static::saving(function($model) {})` function.

I do not want that to happen.

How can I find If user changed nothing and its a blank submit button hit?

Of course before update I can fetch the current values and compare them with input `$request->all()` and decide to update or not, but Is there any better way to do so the laravel way?

Thanks,
K

Comment: Is there a way to find out who down voted the question. You should be only allowed to down vote if you have a reason. It is very frustrating to see a down vote without a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 methods one is `getDirty()` by using this you will get current changed input value, another one is `getOriginal()` if you use that you will get what previous data you have

By using those 2 methods i am giving here a example,may be it will help you

```
static::saving(function($model)
{
foreach($model->getDirty() as $attribute => $value){
    $original= $model->getOriginal($attribute);
    echo "Changed $attribute from '$original' to '$value'<br/>\r\n";
}
return true; //if false the model wont save! 
});
```